# Set Variable Equal To String and Variable

Tags: php, ajax

I would like to set a variable equal to a string and a variable. The variable is a string as well coming through AJAX. I know `$data3` is coming through because when I change `file_put_contents('TestFile.json', $updated);` to `file_put_contents('TestFile.json', $data3);` it works. So there's no problem with the AJAX.

I know this is not proper JSON at all, I'm just testing. The value of `$data3` is the string "string". So what I want the outcome to be is "Testing string".

BELOW IS THE CURRENT CODE:
`<?php 
        $data3 = $_REQUEST ["data3"];
        $updated = 'Testing ' + $data3;
        file_put_contents('TestFile.json', $updated); 
        ?>`

Comment: 'Testing' + $data is invalid. You use . to concatenate strings in PHP;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to add two strings together with a JAVA style operation (+). In PHP you use . to concatenate.

```
$data3 = $_REQUEST['data3'];
$updated = 'Testing ' . $data3;
file_put_contents('TestFile.json', $updated);
```

Comment: Thanks. Will give check when I can.